# Nested for loop to lambda - Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm trying to replace java for loop with a lambda.

I have at first a class `Arrs:`

```
public class Arrs {

    private boolean isX;

    public boolean isX() {
        return isX;
    }

    public void setX(boolean x) {
        isX = x;
    }
}
```

Then I have a class called `Example:`

```
public class Example {

    private Arrs[] arrs;

    public Arrs[] getArrs() {
        return arrs;
    }

    public void setArrs(Arrs[] arrs) {
        this.arrs = arrs;
    }
}
```

Then in my main I want to count the total times of true value of `isX` variable.
Using pure Java for-loop the code is:

```
int count = 0;
for(Example anExample : exampleList) {
    for(Arrs anArray : anExample.getArrs()) {
        if(anArray.isX()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

With lambda I tried the following:

```
Stream<Object> x = a.map(anArray -> {
    return Arrays.stream(anArray).filter(array -> array.isX()).count();
});
```

But it does not return the correct number of element.

Comment: Not the best idea to call your class `Array`.

Comment: It is just sample code.

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana this is bad even an example, I think you should change the change the name!

Comment: Please, stay focus on the question.

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana calling a class `Array` which itself doesn't represent an array, is simply missleading, and just leads to further confusion. Making it hard to really focus on your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could just use `flatMap` and `filter`:

```java
long count = exampleList.stream()
    .flatMap(example -> Arrays.stream(example.getArrs()))
    .filter(Arrs::isX) // Arrs::isX == arr -> arr.isX()
    .count();
```

First, we're streaming over the list of examples, and *flat map* each element to `getArrs()`. Flat mapping makes sure that all elements of all `getArrs()` are present in a single stream.

Then we just filter by the predicate `arr.isX()`. At last, we call `count()` on the stream, which returns the number of (remaining) elements.

Answer (score 2):

same flatmap, but with reduce instead of filter+count:

```
exampleList.stream()
    .flatMap(example -> Arrays.stream(example.getArrs()))
    .reduce(0, (total, arr) -> arr.isX() ? total+1 : 0);
```

reduce is a nice little function that goes over a stream and does something to each element while "carrying over" a value.

more on the subject [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce)

Answer (score -1):

You are not getting objects from exampleList. Here is a piece of code that you are trying to achieve. :)

```
long x = exampleList.stream().map(example-> {
            return Arrays
                    .stream(example.getArrs())
                    .filter(array -> array.isX())
                    .count();
        }).count();
```

Comment: You're now only counting the amount of elements in the original list, and not the amount of arrays that match `array.isX()`, you probably meant to use `mapToLong` and then `sum`